# Is caching Vercel insights recommended for a Next.js app and how do I implement it?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

Should I Cache Vercel Insights in a Next.js App and How to Implement It ?

I'm developing a Next.js app hosted on Vercel and considering implementing caching for Vercel insights. I'm curious about the benefits and best practices of caching Vercel insights, and I'd appreciate guidance on how to implement it effectively . Any advice or recommendations on this topic would be greatly appreciated .

Comment: You can refer to the Vercel Insights script at the following URL : https://khashayarghajar.com/_vercel/insights/script.js .